# how can i improve performance of this python code to remove duplicates from multiple files

Tags: python

i am trying to remove duplicates from multiple text files

Eg: 1.txt

ABC

CDE

FGH

2.txt

ABC < Don't want this as it is already present in 1.txt

XYZ

then i don't want ABC in any other text files

I came up with a python code to solve this problem but its taking too much of time and gets slower since the set keeps on growing i have around 100gb of data. Is there anyway through which i can improve the speed of this code or any other alternative approach for this problem?

```py
main_list = get_all_stored_emails()
paths_checked =get_all_crawled_paths()
emails = set()
if main_list is None:
    main_list = set()
if paths_checked is None:
    paths_checked = set()

for r, d, f in os.walk("C:/Hash/"): 
    for file in f:
        if '.txt' in file and os.path.join(r, file) not in paths_checked:       
            for lines in open(os.path.join(r, file)):           
                em = lines.strip()
                if em not in main_list:
                    emails.add(em)
                    main_list.add(em)
            save_as_newfile(emails) 
            save_mainlist_to_file(main_list)
            save_done_so_far(os.path.join(r, file))
            emails = set()
```

Comment: Use something other than Python.

Comment: Instead of holding strings, hold their hash code, for example their md5. You have 1/2^64 risk of two strings producing the same hash code. You can also write your own C++ class (or use someone's), that export a method, that returns true, if string was already seen previously and use that class from python. Writing extending class in C++ using `boost::python` is rather simple, i've done it several times, so its no brainer and should boost your performance by order easily, maybe two when coupled with using hash of string instead of string.

Comment: `'.txt' in file` -> `file.endswith('.txt') - small optimisation, with yours it was checking the whole length of the filename and only hitting at the end, with mine it only checks the end